# How to add App Shortcuts into React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-appshortcut

I've been seen on Android we have something like this:
[React Native App Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8thh.jpg)

So, I was wondering if I could do something like that in react native cli, no expo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher, you can define shortcuts to specific actions in your app. These shortcuts can be displayed in a supported launcher. Shortcuts let your users quickly start common or recommended tasks within your app.

```
npm install react-native-app-shortcuts --save
```

Here is [link](https://github.com/lokyoung/react-native-app-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can install Android shortcut in React Native. Try
$ npm install react-native-app-shortcuts --save
$ react-native link react-native-app-shortcuts

and then import the package:
import RNAppShortcuts from 'react-native-app-shortcuts';